# Can I use Did his girlfriend leave him ? with the answer Yes, it's been 2 months now

Tags: questions

We were just asked to make a question to fit this answer:

> Yes, it's been 2 months now.

I used :

> Did his girlfriend leave him ?

... and the teacher said it was not correct and I don't understand why.

Comment: Yes, those sentences are grammatical and make sense. If you can add more details and be specific about what you're confused about, we can write a response with more details as to why.

Comment: We were just asked to make a question to fit this answer, I used Did she leve..and the teacher said it was not correct....

Comment: I think you have to ask your teacher why he or she said it was not correct.  It sounds OK to this US English speaker too.  Maybe your teacher was looking for a question like "Has his girlfriend left him?" because the answer has "Yes, it's (*it has*) been two months now."  By the way, we don't put a space between a question mark and the word before it when writing English.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I've edited your question to include the information from your comment. If you feel I haven't expressed your question correctly, please feel free to [edit] it. It helps us to write better answers if we understand as much as possible about why you're asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Some non-native speakers think that an answer should has the same tense as a question. So In these case your reply could be :

> Has his girlfriend already left him ?
>   
> Yes, it's been 2 months now.

or

> Did his girlfriend leave him ?
>   
> Yes, it was 2 months ago.

But my experience shows that native speakers mix them very often.